# The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure ERROR in c# during sending mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, certificate, sendmail, vps

i have my own vps(windows server 2008 -r2 , dns and iis installed , remote access) and every thing is ok about that.
i installed MDaemon(for getting a little mail server) in that vps and configured it by it's documents.
now webadmin and webclient of mdaemon are ok and i can send and recieve mails by them.(to gmail - yahoo - etc)
i tried to connect my outlook 2010 to a mdaemon's mail and figured out encryption is disable on mdaemon.(without encryption every thing was ok and outlook worked perfect)
outlook account settings of that mail without encryption is like below (created automatically by outlook) :

[image]

[image]

[image]

my goal is sending mails (using mdaemon mail account) by c# codes.
for enabling encryption of mdaemon's mails i went to it's security menu and changed it like below :

[image]

as you see i checked two areas :
1-enable ssl,starttls, and stls
2-smtp server uses starttls whenever possible
the important part of previous picture is mail.soscharge.com certificate.
without creating that certificate (by hitting create certificate button in ssl and tls -> mdaemon tab) i could n't enable ssl because of mdaemon's error like below :

[image]

at now i tried connect outlook 2010 to that mdaemon's mail account again.
this time i got an error about certificate that tells you should add untrusted certificate to trusted zones, so i did it and could create that account successfully like below :

[image]

[image]

[image]

i changed mail.soscharge.com to imap.soscharge.com for incoming mail server and it worked too.

now it's c# codes turn...

i wrote the codes below :

```
namespace CardCharge
{
    public partial class Email : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendCardsByEmail(
                    "support@soscharge.com",
                    "FromExplain",
                    "To@gmail.com",
                    "Subject",
                    "htmlEmailBody",
                    "support@soscharge.com",
                    "blablabla"
                 );
        }

        private void SendCardsByEmail(string FromEmail, string FromExplain, string To, string Subject, string htmlEmailBody, string SenderEmail, string SenderPassword)
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress(FromEmail, FromExplain, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            mail.To.Add(To);

            mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            mail.Subject = Subject;
            //mail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html; -> This Is For .Net 1.1
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            mail.Body = htmlEmailBody;

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(SenderEmail, SenderPassword);
            smtp.Host = "smtp.soscharge.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            //smtp.Port = 25;
            smtp.Timeout = 18000000;

            try
            {
                smtp.Send(mail);

                Response.Write("Email Was Sent Successfully");
            }

            catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpException exp)
            {
                Response.Write(exp.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and it's error :

> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation
>   procedure.

[image]

what does this error mean and how can i fix this error?

really appreciate for attention and help.